# Why does this parallel binary search take more time than the sequential one?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, binary-search

I have the following code in openMP c++ that runs iterative binary search sequentially and parallely. According to the output, why parallel search is taking more time than the sequential one even after running 4 sections parallely?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;

#define MAX1 500000

int binary_search(int arr[], int x, int low, int high)
{
    while(low <= high)
    {
        int mid = low + (high-low)/2;
        if(arr[mid] == x)
            return mid;
        if(arr[mid] < x)
            low = mid + 1;
        else
            high = mid - 1;
    }
    return -1;
}

void binary()
{
    int array[MAX1];
    int loc, loc1, loc2, loc3, loc4, k;
    omp_set_num_threads(4);

    for(int i=0; i<MAX1; ++i)
        array[i] = rand()%1000;

    sort(array, array+MAX1);

    cout<<"Enter number to search : ";
    cin>>k;
    int mid = MAX1/2;
    double start_time = omp_get_wtime();
    loc1 = binary_search(array, k, 0, mid);
    loc2 = binary_search(array, k, mid+1, MAX1-1);
    double end_time = omp_get_wtime()-start_time;
    cout<<loc1<<"\t"<<loc2<<endl;
    cout<<"Sequential Binary search runtime : "<<end_time<<endl;

    int one_quart = mid/2;
    int three_quart = 3*one_quart;
    start_time = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
        loc1 = binary_search(array, k, 0, one_quart);
        #pragma omp section
        loc2 = binary_search(array, k, one_quart+1, mid);
        #pragma omp section
        loc3 = binary_search(array, k, mid+1, three_quart);
        #pragma omp section
        loc4 = binary_search(array, k, three_quart+1, MAX1-1);
    }
    end_time = omp_get_wtime()-start_time;
    cout<<loc1<<"\t"<<loc2<<"\t"<<loc3<<"\t"<<loc4<<endl;
    cout<<"Parallel Binary search runtime : "<<end_time<<endl;
}
```

Output:

Enter number to search : 777

-1  388671

Sequential Binary search runtime : 3.478e-06

-1  -1  -1  388671

Parallel Binary search runtime : 0.000629687

Comment: I'd say it's likely because you're only searching through 500,000 elements - for a balanced binary search three, that's just 19 operations, worst-case. The overhead of running the threads in parallel is probably resulting in slower performance than you'd experience just running it sequentially. If you can, try scaling the program up, and let us know what the results are.

Comment: Perhaps because the single core's cache was already hot, having just sorted the array just now, while all the other cores had to wait for slow RAM.

Comment: `log2(500000)` is ~19, meaning a binary search will have to do roughly 19 comparisons to find the result in the worse case. That's basically nothing.

Comment: I'm having an issue with parallel processing of a binary search.  If the value is found in one of the quarters, the other quarters are still running.  Also, there needs to be extra code to find out which quarter contains the value.  Is there any significant benefit to making a binary search run in parallel?

Comment: 19 comparisons (worse case) vs 200 to 300 extra instructions per thread to set them up.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I agree. Binary search is itself a divide and conquer strategy, does not need parallelization. But, its an assignment. log2(500000) being ~19 is itself enough faster.

Comment: Since the code is incomplete (there is no main program) it's impossible to tell, but if you just call this from main without doing anything  else, you are also timing all of the cost of initialising the parallel runtime and creating threads. You should warm that up with and empty omp parallel outside the timing region. (In main, for instance...)